# Proving a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

$G$ is an abelian group. Let $H = \{a \in G; a^3 = e\}$
Need to show that $H$ is a subgroup. I am not sure about the last one -closure under inverses:

1. $H \ne \varnothing$ since $e^3 = eee = e$, so $e \in H$
2. Let $a, b \in H$. Then $a^3 = e$ and $b^3 = e$,
   $$
   (ab)^3 = ababab = aaabbb = a^3b^3 = ee = e
   $$
   (since $G$ is abelian).  Thus, $ab \in H$
3. Let $a \in H$, $$aa^{-1} = e$$
   $$aa^{-1} = aaa$$
   $$a^{-1} = aa$$
   Check: $a(aa) = e$, $(aa)a = e$.

Comment: It is fine, but I would rather write $(aa)a=a(aa)=e$, so the inverse of $a$, namely $a^2$, is in $H$.

Comment: Once you establish that for $a \in H$, $a^{-1} = a^2$, just check that $(a^{-1})^3 = (a^2)^3 = a^6 = (a^3)^2 = e^2 = e$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, if you want, take it from there: 
$$(a^{-1} )^3=aa\cdot aa\cdot aa=aaa\cdot aaa=e^2=e$$

But of course also 
$$ (a^{-1})^3=(a^3)^{-1}=e^{-1}=e$$